How to download imagery to a Google Drive folder using GEE Python API given new constraints on Google Cloud projects
I am currently trying to update a Python script that uses GEE API to request Landsat imagery. Before the introduction of Google Cloud Projects, I used the command ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**export_options) in order to store these images in my Google drive. I have since updated my code to adjust for using a Google Cloud Project; however, despite the task manager saying the download has completed, when I press the option to view in Drive it says that the contents are empty.
I've added a ton of permissions within the service account I'm using for my credentials but have had no luck getting the data to store.
Any tips/suggestions?
